# How to delete amazon cognito user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, amazon-cognito

I want to delete cognito user using my nodejs application.

**Example**

```
cognitoUser.deleteUser (err, result) ->
  if err
    reject err
  resolve result
```

when i try to delete cognito user error throws as follows

```
Error: User is not authenticated
```

**cognitoUser.deleteUser** is used by an authenticated user to delete himself but i want to delete all users using super user

Please give me some idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the main aws javascript SDK and call the adminDeleteUser operation. It is an authenticated operation and it will require developer credentials for you to call it.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/apis/cognito-idp-2016-04-18.normal.json#L100

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
var client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: 'us-east-1' });

//now you can call adminDeleteUser on the client object
```

Comment: @lonut Trestian, Thank you for your answer, i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You can do from AWS-CLI

```
aws cognito-idp admin-delete-user --user-pool-id ${user pool id} --username ${username usually email here}
```

Comment: They asked for how to do it in a nodeJS application, not from the cli...